# Why stripe.Charge.list(limit=1,starting_after=) gives me the Invalid String error?

Tags: python, string

The below code gives me an error:

```
newer_charge=stripe.Charge.list(limit=1)
                
older_charge=stripe.Charge.list(limit=1,starting_after=newer_charge)
```

The error is:

`stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Invalid string: ~~~~~~~~`

where `~~~~~~~~` is the exact string that is seen when printing `print(newer_chrage)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the issue:

```
newer_charge=stripe.Charge.list(limit=1)
                
older_charge=stripe.Charge.list(limit=1,starting_after=newer_charge.data[0])
```